# automated test dont match manual test

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have the following feature:

```
@javascript
Scenario: Yahoo sign-in
    Given I am on the "Yahoo" login page #login.yahoo.com
    And I click the "#yucs-login_signIn" link
    When I enter "valid_user" into the "username" field
    And I enter "valid_password" into the "passwd" field
    And I click the "#pLabelC" link #keep me signed in check box
    And I click the ".save" button
    Then I should see "Hi, <<username>>"
```

but when the test is run, the test gets hung up right after login.  Not actually logged in.  If I take control of the browser and complete the login it works!

I tried using ***show_me_the_cookies*** gem but there are are no cookies for me to clear.
Here are my form fields filling steps:

```
When /^I click the "(.*)" (button|link)$/ do |btn_or_link,ctl|
  case ctl
    when "button"
      click_button(btn_or_link)
    when "link"
      find(btn_or_link).click
    else
      puts "error"
  end
end

When(/^I enter "(.*)" into the "(.*)" field$/) do |value, field|
  fill_in(field, :with=>value)
end
```

Does Yahoo have some "magic" ontheir website that I need to take into account

Comment: When /^I click the "(.*)" (button|link)$/ do |btn_or_link,ctl|
   case ctl
      when "button"
         click_button(btn_or_link)
      when "link"
         find(btn_or_link).click
      else
         puts "error"
   end
end


When(/^I enter "(.*)" into the "(.*)" field$/) do |value, field|
   fill_in(field, :with=>value)
end

Comment: So what step does your scenario stop at? What do you see at your screen before the test fails? What is the test failure message?

Comment: Then I should see "Hi, <<username>>"

Comment: Then I should see "Hi, <<username>>".  The problem is that the login fails in my test, but works when done manually.  ERROR: expected to find text "Hi, Chester" in "Yahoo Mail Sign In Help Keep me signed in Sign In I can't access my account Help OR Create New Account Sign in with Facebook or Google Terms | Privacy" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError).  For some reason my test gets to a page between being logged in and not. I have to enter  my login password twice!

Comment: Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I had to repeat the steps you take to see that "pre-logged-in" page which you described. Here it is: 
[image]

As we see, the real name at the right-top corner and a nickname are already displayed, but a repeated input is required. The problem is that we are not completely sure if this form is going to appear every time, so we need some fancy logics to pass it. Here is what I ended up with:

```
And I click the ".save" button
And I verify my password if it is required
Then I should see "Hi, <<username>>"
```

The idea here is to fill in the secondary password prompt only if it exists:

```
And /^I verify my password if it is required$/ do
  sleep(2) # just to be completely sure the form was displayed
  # in case there is no secondary form, we do not try to input password
  if page.has_css?('#loginBox #login_form #passwd') and page.has_content?('Sign In')
    step %Q{I enter "#{@password}" into the "passwd" field}
    step %Q{I click the ".save" button}
  end
end
```

I set up `@password`variable here

```
When(/^I enter "(.*)" into the "(.*)" field$/) do |value, field|
  if field == 'passwd' then @password = value end
  fill_in(field, :with=>value)
end
```

but it should be fine just to copy-paste your password filling step with plain value.

Applying this logics did let me to pass to yahoo's main page as logged user.

However, you should beware of logging in like that, as services like yahoo ask users to verify themselves with captcha from time to time (and it's not easy to walk around).

Let me also share an idea of debugging this kind of tricky scenarios. Your best friends here are `sleep` method and [pry gem](https://github.com/pry/pry). Head up to the failing step of your scenario, set a huge `sleep` or `binding.pry` there and check if HTML code of the page has the elements which satisfy your selectors, page contains the required text etc. That could give you a tip on which additional steps should be implemented (or edited).